# Random::string deprecated?

Tags: 8

I'm using *Random* class to generate a password for a new user in my custom module.

I added the namespace in my module controller: `use \Drupal\Component\Utility\Random;`
And I am using it like this:

```
$user = User::create();
$user->setPassword(Random::string());
```

Problem is this function seems to be deprecated, however I found it in the [Drupal API documentation](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Component%21Utility%21Random.php/function/Random%3A%3Astring/8.2.x). 
Here is the error I get:

> Deprecated function: Non-static method Drupal\Component\Utility\Random::string()

Did I use it wrong or do you know a better way to generate a random string ?

*Drupal version: 8.4*

Comment: user_password()

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Random::string` isn't a static function, so you can't call it statically.

Well, you can (PHP is, erm, interesting like that), but it will throw a fatal error in future versions of the language, hence the warning now. To clarify, you're not being warned that `Random::string` itself is deprecated, just the method you're using to invoke it.

Get an instance instead and use that:

```
$random = new \Drupal\Component\Utility\Random();
$string = $random->string();
```

Comment: Oh right, I'm new to namespaces so I thought ... I don't know what I thought.

Comment: Don't overlook what Ivan said, if you are trying to generate a password, there is a function for that. https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21user%21user.module/function/user_password/8.4.x